# How to simplify enable_if alias in template template parameter

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, variadic-templates, sfinae

My goal is to have a struct that takes in an alias to a specialized `enable_if_t<>` along with a typename variadic parameter pack and then tells me whether the `enable_if`'s conditions were satisfied for all of the types in the pack. I have a bunch of these specialized `enable_if`s, but need to write tests for them before we can put them into our open source project. I have about 2000+ lines of code manually testing these specializations, but bet I can get it to 100 or 200 if I can figure out the pattern below. I have a working version (+ godbolt link), but tbh I'm not sure why it's working and that scheme is breaking in a case where the implementation receives a parameter pack

Here is an example of the code I would like to write and it's result. I'm using C++14 and can steal basic implementations of things from C++17 likes conjunction and void_t

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

// enable_if for arithmetic types
template <typename T>
using require_arithmetic = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>;

const bool true_arithmetic = require_tester<require_arithmetic, double, int, float>::value;
// output: true

// If any of the types fail the enable_if the result is false
const bool false_arithmetic = require_tester<require_arithmetic, double, std::string, float>::value;
// output: false
```

The below does do what I want, but tbf I'm not really understanding how.

```cpp
// Base impl
 template <template <class> class Check, typename T1, typename = void>
 struct require_tester_impl : std::false_type {};

 // I'm not totally sure why void_t needs to be here?
 template <template <class> class Check, typename T1> 
 struct require_tester_impl<Check, T1, void_t<Check<T1>>> : std::true_type {};

 // The recursive version (stolen conjuction from C++17)
 template <template <class> class Check, typename T = void, typename... Types>
 struct require_tester {
  static const bool value = conjunction<require_tester_impl<Check, T>,
   require_tester<Check, Types...>>::value;
 };

// For the end
 template <template <class> class Check>
 struct require_tester<Check, void> : std::true_type {} ;
```

In particular, I'm not sure why the void_t is needed in the `impl` partial specialization for `std::true_type`.

What I would like to get to is a `require_variadic_tester` that takes in a variadic templated alias, something like `enable_if<conjunction<check<T...>>::value>`, and gives me true or false. Sadly, the below returns false no matter what types come in

```cpp
// impl
template <template <class...> class Check, typename... Types>
struct require_variadic_impl : std::false_type {};

// Adding void_t here causes the compiler to not understand the partial specialiation
template <template <class...> class Check, typename... Types>
struct require_variadic_impl<Check, Check<Types...>> : std::true_type {};

template <template <class...> class Check, typename... Types>
struct require_variadic_tester : require_variadic_impl<Check, Types...> {};
```

I would like the following given the input, but can't seem to shake how to hide that conjunction one level lower

```cpp
// Enable if for checking if all types are arithmetic
template <typename... Types>
using require_all_arithmetic = std::enable_if_t<conjunction<std::is_arithmetic<Types>...>::value>;

require_variadic_tester<require_all_arithmetic, double, double, double>::value;
// is true

require_variadic_tester<require_all_arithmetic, double, std::string, double>::value;
// is false
```

I think my failure to understand `void_t` in the first meta function is causing my misunderstanding

Below is the godbolt, any help in understanding this is very appreciated!

https://godbolt.org/z/8XNqpo

#### Edit:

To give more context in why I want the above with the conjunction inside of the `enable_if_t`. I'm stuck on C++14 but we are adding a new feature to our open source math library which without more generic types (and requirements on those generic types) we will end up with a ton of code bloat. We currently have stuff like this

```cpp
template <int R, int C>
inline Eigen::Matrix<double, R, C> add(
    const Eigen::Matrix<double, R, C>& m1, const Eigen::Matrix<double, R, C>& m2) {
  return m1 + m2;
}
```

I'd like to have more generic templates and do something like this

```cpp
template <typename Mat1, typename Mat2,
  require_all_eigen<is_arithmetic, Mat1, Mat2>...>
inline auto add(Mat1&& m1, Mat2&& m2) {
  return m1 + m2;
}
```

I have all of those `require_*_<container>` aliases setup, but the tests for all of those requires is about 2000+ lines and in the future that will be a funky mess to have to deal with.

We have unary and variadic template enable_if aliases, at this point the above unary case does what I want ala a nice test like

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(requires, arithmetic_test) {
  EXPECT_FALSE((require_tester<require_arithmetic, std::string>::value));
  EXPECT_TRUE((require_tester<require_arithmetic, double, int, float>::value));
}
```

The issue I have is with testing the variadic template enable_if aliases, where I want to be able to write something like

```cpp
// Enable if for checking if all types are arithmetic 
template <typename... Types>
using require_all_arithmetic = std::enable_if_t<conjunction<std::is_arithmetic<Types>...>::value>;
/// For the tests

TEST(requires, arithmetic_all_test) {
  EXPECT_FALSE((require_variadic_tester<require_all_arithmetic, std::string,
     Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>>::value));
  EXPECT_TRUE((require_variadic_tester<require_all_arithmetic,
     double, int, float>::value));
}
```

If I can test all of this I think the `requires` part of our library alone could be a nice header only mini-library for what I'm calling "bad fake concepts in 14" (or bfc14 for short ;-))

Comment: To answer your first question: If `Check<T1>` is ill-formed then `require_tester_impl<Check, T1, void>` will be a derivation of `false_type` since template substitution fails during the specialization, falling back to non-specialized implementation, whereas if it's well formed it will be successfully specialized as a derivation of `true_type`.

Comment: Thanks! I think what I'm not understanding specifically is why `Check<T1>` being ill formed does not cause SFINAE to go off and use the non partial specialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what happens with your `require_tester<require_arithmetic, double, double, int>`:

This doesn't match the partial specialization of `require_tester`, which has just two template arguments `<Check, void>`, so we use the primary template

```
template <template <class> class Check, typename T, typename... Types>
struct require_tester;
```

with `Check = require_arithmetic`; `T = double`; `Types = double, int`. It does not match the partial specialization of `require_tester`. Member `value` is the result of

```
conjunction<require_tester_impl<Check, T>, require_tester<Check, Types...>>::value
```

where the interesting part is `require_tester_impl<Check, T> = require_tester_impl<require_arithmetic, double>`. First, since the template parameters of `require_tester_impl` are

```
template <template <class> class Check, typename T1, typename = void>
```

and only two explicit template argumetns are given, we know the actual template arguments are `<require_arithmetic, double, void>`. Now we need to see whether or not this matches the partial specialization of `require_template_impl`, so we try to match:

```
require_template_impl<require_arithmetic, double, void>
require_template_impl<Check, T1, void_t<Check<T1>>>
```

So template argument deduction finds `Check = require_arithmetic` and `T1 = double`. The type `void_t<Check<T1>>` does not cause any deduction of `Check` or `T1`. But the deduced parameter values must be substituted in, and we find `void_t<Check<T1>>` is `void_t<require_arithmetic<double>>` is `void`. This does match the `void` from the template arguments, so the partial specialization does match, and `require_template_impl<require_arithmetic, double, void>` inherits `std::true_type`, not `std::false_type`.

On the other hand, if `T1` were `std::string` instead of `double`, substituting the deduced template arguments in would find `void_t<require_arithmetic<std::string>>` is invalid, via the eventual `enable_if<`...`>::type` where no member `type` exists. When substituting deduced template arguments into other template parameters fails, this means the partial specialization is thrown out as not a match. So `require_template_impl<require_arithmetic, std::string, void>` uses the primary template and inherits `std::false_type`.

Going back to the `value` member of `require_tester`, it recursively finds `require_tester<require_arithmetic, double, int>::value` via `require_tester<require_arithmetic, int>::value` via `require_tester<require_arithmetic>::value` which is the same as `require_tester<require_arithmetic, void>::value`.  All the `value` members are true, so the final `value` is true.

Though I would simplify this a bit:

1. The `void` is unnecessary in the `require_tester` recursion, and causes the strange "fact" that `require_tester<Anything, void>::value` is always true. It would be better to remove the `= void` default from the primary `require_tester` template, and make the base case `template <template <class> class Check> require_tester<Check>` instead.
2. Your `value` expression in the `require_tester` primary template is always giving exactly two template arguments to `conjunction`, so it's not really using its variadic property, and you could just as well write `require_tester_impl<`...`>::value && require_tester<`...`>::value`. Since `require_tester` is doing a recursion itself, it doesn't need the recursive definition abstracted into `conjunction`. Instead, `require_tester` could be simplified to count on `conjunction` and avoid doing any recursion itself:

   ```
   template <template <class> class Check, typename... Types>
   struct require_tester : conjunction<require_tester_impl<Check, Types>...>
   {};
   // No other specialization needed.
   ```

The `require_variadic_tester` template can follow a similar pattern, except that I'll give the dummy template parameter which was just `typename = void` a name, `typename Enable`. And it needs to come before the template parameter pack, so it's not that useful to actually default it to `void`, and we need to make sure to use the appropriate `void` template argument in the corresponding position.

```
template <template <class...> class Check, typename Enable, typename... Types>
struct require_variadic_impl : std::false_type {};

template <template <class...> class Check, typename... Types>
struct require_variadic_impl<Check, void_t<Check<Types...>>, Types...> : std::true_type {};

template <template <class...> class Check, typename... Types>
struct require_variadic_tester : require_variadic_impl<Check, void, Types...> {};
```

See [the modified program on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zrRz-g), with desired results.

Comment: That answer is gorgeous,  sleek, dare I say even sexy. Thank you so much for the explanation and code!!

Answer (score 0):

```
template <template <class> class Check, typename T1, typename = void>
struct require_tester_impl : std::false_type {};

// I'm not totally sure why void_t needs to be here?
template <template <class> class Check, typename T1> 
struct require_tester_impl<Check, T1, void_t<Check<T1>>> : std::true_type {};
```

Here, you required the third parameter of `require_tester_impl` is of type `void`, since you wrote it as default value. If the user, when specializing `require_tester_impl` doesn't specify its third parameter, it is `void`. So the compiler will search for a partial specialization where the first template parameter is a unary class template, the second template parameter is a type, and the third one is `void`, otherwise, no partial specialization will be found, since the third parameter of any partial specialization will fail.

That's where `void_t` comes into play. Since you want to inject `Check` into the parameter, but you require `void`, that's when `void_t` comes handy, since every type used to specialized it is mapped to `void`, which is what you really need. When the partial specialization doesn't fail, you will have two enabled specializations, the default one, and the partial one.

The partial one will be finally choosen since it is more specialized than the other, since `void` have been calculated in a way dependant on other template parameters.

That's for the first part. For the second part (the variadic template), remember that, if  `enable_if` succeds, it returns `void`.

So your `require_variadic_impl`:

```
template <template <class...> class Check, typename... Types>
struct require_variadic_impl : std::false_type {};

// Adding void_t here causes the compiler to not understand the partial specialiation
template <template <class...> class Check, typename... Types>
struct require_variadic_impl<Check, Check<Types...>> : std::true_type {};
```

have a problem here, and it's that, `Check<Types...>`, since it is aliased to `enable_if`, returns `void` when it success, however, the second parameter of `require_variadic_impl` is not `void` so the partial specializations finally fails when the check is correct. When it isn't, then the `enable_if` have no inner type defined,the partial specialization also fails, and the base case is used again.

However, do it simple. I propose here a much more readable implementation with same final result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<class... Ts>
struct require_all_arithmetic : std::conjunction<std::is_arithmetic<Ts>...>
{};

template<template<class...> class Check, class... Ts>
struct require_variadic_tester : Check<Ts...>
{};

int main()
{
    std::cout << require_variadic_tester<require_all_arithmetic, double, double, double>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << require_variadic_tester<require_all_arithmetic, double, std::string, double>::value << std::endl;
}
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9fb68e04eb0ad40

Or just:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<class... Ts>
struct require_all_arithmetic : std::conjunction<std::is_arithmetic<Ts>...>
{};

int main()
{
    std::cout << require_all_arithmetic<double, double, double>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << require_all_arithmetic<double, std::string, double>::value << std::endl;
}
```

However, if you require a check that is sfinae-friendly, plus a struct that maps "sfinae"-friendly checks to `true`/`false`, you can use `constexpr` methods instead. It's much more simple:

```
template<class... Ts>
using require_all_arithmetic = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction<std::is_arithmetic<Ts>...>::value>;

template<template<class...> class Check, class... Ts, class = Check<Ts...> >
constexpr bool require_variadic_tester_impl(int)
{ return true; }

template<template<class...> class Check, class... Ts>
constexpr bool require_variadic_tester_impl(unsigned)
{ return false; }

template<template<class...> class Check, class... Ts>
struct require_variadic_tester
{ static constexpr bool value = require_variadic_tester_impl<Check, Ts...>(42); };

int main()
{
    std::cout << require_variadic_tester<require_all_arithmetic, double, double, double>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << require_variadic_tester<require_all_arithmetic, double, std::string, double>::value << std::endl;
}
```

The technique works as follow: if `Check` fails, only the second overload will compile, which returns `false`. However, if the check is valid and the inner `enable_if` is defined, then both overloads will be valid but, since you have passed an `int` (`42`), and the second overload receives an `unsigned`, the first overload will be a better match, returning `true`.

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfe22ea099dd5749

Finally, if you want the check always is `true_type` or `false_type`, then, instead of inheriting, you can just alias `std::conditional`:

```
template<template<class...> class Check, class... Ts>
using require_variadic_tester = 
   std::conditional_t<require_variadic_tester_impl<Check, Ts...>(42),
                      std::true_type, std::false_type>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do need the conjunction inside of the enable_if though. I updated the original question with more context

Comment: @Steve_Corrin Edited.

Comment: Wow! I appreciate the answer! Also my apologies, the comment I made above was for another answer but refreshing the post got me jumbled up. Your proposed method is v nice, I've been trying to get our team to move up to C++17 and seeing a little sprinkling of constexpr being cool may help convince them a bit!

Comment: @Steve_Corrin `constexpr` can be used in `C++14` (and C++11 as well). I have compile the examples with `C++17` for `std::conditional`, that's all. Everything else must be valid with a full featured `C++14` compiler.

Comment: Oh I thought constexpr was limited use in C++14 (only in function definitions). I feel like I tried them a while ago and our windows build was v unhappy about it. I'll play around with this though!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand all your needs but...

> What I would like to get to is a `require_variadic_tester` that takes in a variadic templated alias, something like `enable_if<conjunction<check<T...>>::value>`, and gives me true or false. Sadly, the below returns false no matter what types come in

Are you sure that you want `conjunction<check<T...>>` ?

Or do you want `conjunction<check<T>...>`?

I mean... the check must receive a variadic list of types or do you want to check a an alias, that (as in your example) receive a single type and a conjunction that is true iff (if and only if) the check is satisfied for all types?

In this second case, `std::void_t` is very handy to verify that all checks are satisfied.

I propose the following `require_variadic_impl` and `require_variadic_tester`

```
template <template <typename> class, typename, typename = void>
struct require_variadic_impl
   : public std::false_type 
 { };

template <template <typename> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct require_variadic_impl<C, std::tuple<Ts...>, std::void_t<C<Ts>...>>
   : public std::true_type
 { };

template <template <typename> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct require_variadic_tester
   : public require_variadic_impl<C, std::tuple<Ts...>>
 { };
```

Now from

```
template <typename T>
using require_arithmetic = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>;

// ...

printf("\nGeneric Variadic: \n\n");
const char* string_generic_var_check = 
  require_variadic_tester<require_arithmetic, std::string>::value ? "true" : "false";
const char* double_generic_var_check = 
  require_variadic_tester<require_arithmetic, double, double, double>::value ? "true" : "false";
std::printf("\t String: %s\n", string_generic_var_check);
std::printf("\t Double: %s\n", double_generic_var_check);
```

you get

```
Generic Variadic: 

     String: false
     Double: true
```

> think my failure to understand `void_t` in the first meta function is causing my misunderstanding

Try thinking `std::void_t<Ts...>` as "enable if all `Ts` are enabled".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The void_t makes more sense now. Though I do need the conjunction inside of the enable_if though. I updated the original question with more context

Comment: @Steve_Corrin - it seems to me that you require `template <typename... Types>
using require_all_arithmetic = std::void_t<std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<Types>>...>`. The "conjunction inside" is `std::void_t`.

Comment: I'd like to leave the void_t on the outside of the require_all_arithmetic since it's not needed when require_*s are used in the function templates